# error when trying to discard dependency and build a project with maven

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, proxy

Good morning I am presenting a problem when executing a `mvn clean install`  to a project with spring boot, I think it may be a problem with proxy, but I already made the proxy settings.

I am new working with maven and spring boot, and I really don't know much about this error, but it seems to me that it is related to proxy

The error I get:

```
C:\Users\E10697\Desktop\Contenedores\oracle_contenedores\Entorno-Oracle-sobre-Docker-master\4. Consumo de la Oracle DB a través de un API Rest\4.1. Elaboración del API Rest\4.1.2. Implementación de una API Rest\OpenwebinarDockerAPI - RESUELTO\OPENWE~1> mvn clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading from spring-milestones: https://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.0.0.M7/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.0.0.M7.pom
Downloading from repository.springframework.maven.release: http://maven.springframework.org/milestone/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.0.0.M7/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.0.0.M7.pom
Downloading from org.springframework: http://maven.springframework.org/snapshot/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.0.0.M7/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.0.0.M7.pom
Downloading from spring-milestone: http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.0.0.M7/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.0.0.M7.pom
Downloading from spring-release: http://repo.spring.io/libs-release/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.0.0.M7/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.0.0.M7.pom
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.0.0.M7/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.0.0.M7.pom
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for openwebinar.marvel.app:app:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.0.0.M7 from/to spring-milestones (https://repo.spring.io/milestone): Transfer failed for https://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.0.0.M7/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.0.0.M7.pom and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 13, column 10
 @
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project openwebinar.marvel.app:app:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT (C:\Users\E10697\Desktop\Contenedores\oracle_contenedores\Entorno-Oracle-sobre-Docker-master\4. Consumo de la Oracle DB a través de un API Rest\4.1. Elaboración del API Rest\4.1.2. Implementación de una API Rest\OpenwebinarDockerAPI - RESUELTO\OPENWE~1\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for openwebinar.marvel.app:app:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.0.0.M7 from/to spring-milestones (https://repo.spring.io/milestone): Transfer failed for https://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.0.0.M7/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.0.0.M7.pom and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 13, column 10: Connect to repo.spring.io:443 [repo.spring.io/35.241.58.96] failed: Connection timed out: connect -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>openwebinar.marvel.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>app</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>rest-api</name>
    <description>Demo for Openwebinar</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.M7</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>repository.springframework.maven.release</id>
            <name>Spring Framework Maven Release Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>org.springframework</id>
            <url> http://maven.springframework.org/snapshot</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestone</id>
            <name>Spring Maven MILESTONE Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-release</id>
            <name>Spring Maven RELEASE Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <modules>
        <module>app-rest-api</module>
        <module>app-web</module>
    </modules>

</project>
```

for proxy proxy configuration

```
set http_proxy=http://E10697:xxxxxx@10.162.64.36:8080/
set https_proxy=http://E10697:xxxxx@10.162.64.36:8080/
```

Also configure the java_proxy:

[image]

the structure of my project:

[image]

configuring the settings.xml in the ubication C:\ Users \ E10697 \ .m2 :

```
<proxies>

 <!-- Proxy for HTTP -->

    <proxy>

        <id>optional</id>

        <active>true</active>

        <protocol>http</protocol>

        <username>E10697</username>

        <password>xxxxxx</password>

        <host>10.162.64.36</host>

        <port>8080</port>

        <nonProxyHosts>localhost</nonProxyHosts>

    </proxy>


 <!-- Proxy for HTTPS -->

    <proxy>

        <id>optional</id>

        <active>true</active>

        <protocol>https</protocol>

        <username>E10697</username>

        <password>xxxxxx</password>

        <host>10.162.64.36</host>

        <port>8080</port>

        <nonProxyHosts>localhost</nonProxyHosts>

    </proxy>

</proxies>
```

Comment: Did you configure the proxy in the `settings.xml`?

Comment: Could you tell me where that file should go? please, I'm new, I already uploaded the structure of my project

Comment: I attached my proxy settings and nothing

Comment: You have attached your proxy username *AND* password? OMFG :-D

Comment: I don't understand "configuring the settings.xml in the ubication C:\Users\E10697.m2 :" The `settings.xml` is a file that should be created in the `.m2` directory in the user home directory. It has a structure that is described in https://maven.apache.org/settings.html

Comment: @JFMeier You can see better now that it is in the .m2 directory, verify the route well, try to do it with the structure that says the official page

Comment: I'd not make the spring boot starter a _parent_ of your project (it most likely isn't) but a _dependency_.

Comment: Your `settings.xml` seems to miss header and footer. It cannot be complete this way.

Comment: I now have the following error: Failed to execute goal on project app-rest-api: Could not resolve dependencies for project openwebinar.marvel.app:app-rest-api:war:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.oracle:ojdbc7:jar:12.1.0 in spring-milestones (https://repo.spring.io/milestone) -> [Help 1]